# Execute CodeIgniter function using Cron

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron, ovh

I have to setup a cron webjob in the ovh platform.
The script to call will be in a php file 'cron.php'.

I need to execute 2 codeigniter functions, the links will be like this :

http://example.com/index.php/process/send1/

http://example.com/index.php/process/send2/

So i need to execute those links in 'cron.php', do you have any idea how to achieve this ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can still call this link in your crontab

Comment: @SathishRavepati the script to call has to be a php file

Answer (score 0):

You can't call the codeigniter functions directly. Instead you could make a request to each URL to run the function code. You could use the php exec function to run the "wget" command on them to send a request.

In cron.php:

```
exec('wget http://example.com/index.php/process/send1/');
exec('wget http://example.com/index.php/process/send2/');
```

If this fails because of PHP not having permissions to execute the command then try file_get_contents() or curl.

Answer (score 0):

I have setup so many crons in my live projects with this method
http://www.asim.pk/2009/05/14/creating-and-installing-crontabs-using-codeigniter/

Comment: I have to absolutely call those links because they are in another server